# Charge user after status of order is changed with eCommerce

Tags: commerce

I am using the Drupal 7 eCommerce kickstart distribution.

I want to sell service (like cleaning, gardening...), and I want user to be able to create order, but I want to give them ability to do payment after service is done.

Is there any way to do this, to make user able to make payment after they create order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a payment gateway that allows for Authorization Only transactions. This will authorize a certain amount, but will not actually charge the credit card.  This is what gas stations, hotels, etc. do. They charge a preset amount, and then finalize the actual amount later.

commerce_authnet offers this capability. In the settings for the payment gateway you just set Authorize Only.

Once the administrator is ready to finalize the payment, they would go to the Orders page, and choose Payment on the Order.  You then 'capture' the amount to finalize the payment.

You can fine tune who has access to the Payments page on the Permissions page.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have to use Stripe service, sorry I did not mention it in original question.

Comment: I have implemented using Stripe the capture later functionality as I am using Stripe too.  I will clean that up and upload it to github sometime this week.  My implementation is based off of the stable release of 1.0 of Stripe.

Comment: The limitation with Stripe capture later functionality is that you only have a 7 day window to capture. If that isn't going to work for you, you should use commerce_card_onfile and store the user's credit card to be charged later.  I have NOT implemented this functionality yet.

Comment: I finally made a patch which has the authorization only functionality implemented for Stripe.  It has NOT been peer reviewed.  It is based of of the 7.x-1.x dev version of the Sept 15th commit.  https://www.drupal.org/node/2600690